# VueJS - vue in viewport mixins doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, mixins

I want fire my function when viewport is on component, i try use: https://github.com/BKWLD/vue-in-viewport-mixin but doesnt't work. Can someone explain me what im doing wrong? Thanks!

```
<template>
    <div class="box has-text-centered" id='count' v-if='inViewport.now'>
        /.../
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    import * as inViewport from './mixins/vue-in-viewport-mixin';

    export default {
        name: 'Counter',
        data() {
            return {
                 /.../
                inViewport: {
                    now: false
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            count: function() {
                const that = this;
                setInterval(function() {
                    if (that.number < that.numberOfLikes) {
                        that.number += 1
                    }
                }, 1)
            }
        },
        mixins: [inViewport],
        watch: {
            'inViewport.now': function(visible) {
                visible ? this.count() : console.log('not')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

EDIT

Instead, I used https://github.com/Akryum/vue-observe-visibility and it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="box has-text-centered" id='count' v-if='inViewport.now'>
    /.../
</div>
```

If you have v-if at the root tag within the template, it doesn't work properly. Try moving the v-if wither to the parent component from where you are calling this component or else move the v-if one level below like:

```
<div class="box has-text-centered" id='count'>
    <div v-if='inViewport.now'> /../ </div>
</div>
```